# Python Selenium Datepicker select the year, month and day

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker

I am trying to select year, month and date in the datepicker with start and end date respectively:

But with date year and month returns 'TimeoutExceptionerror'

Could someone please help with that? Thanks : )

```
driver.get('http://www.sse.com.cn/disclosure/bond/announcement/company/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
#start
datefield_st = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "start_date")))
datefield_st.click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class,'datetimepicker-years'])[1]//table/tbody/tr/td/span[text()='{}']".format(str(2021))))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class,'datetimepicker-months'])[1]//table/tbody/tr/td/span[text()='{}']".format("一月")))).click()
day=1
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='datetimepicker-days'])[1]//tr/td[text()='{}'][not(contains(@class,'new'))]".format(str(day))))).click()
#enddate
datefield_ed = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "end_date")))
datefield_ed.click()
#same_as_StartDate
```

Comment: wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[12]/div[3]/table/thead/tr[1]/th[2]"))).click() Have you tried clicking the switch class and then using your code. In a year month date order.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath for year and month are invalid.

Instead, you can try the following xpath:

```
#update here
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ms-parent.single_select2 button div")))

#start
datefield_st = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "start_date")))
datefield_st.click()

#startyear
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='datetimepicker-days']//th[contains(text(), '{}')]".format(str(2021))))).click()
#startmonth
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='datetimepicker-months']//table/tbody/tr/td/span[text()='{}']".format("一月")))).click()
```

Or for the month, you can also use:

```
#startmonth
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='datetimepicker-months']//table/tbody/tr/td/span[1]"))).click()
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help, but those paths still returns the timeout error as mine from my side

Comment: I think should click on `class=switch` to switch it first?

Comment: @Cathy after perform `datefield_st.click()`, is the date picker appear?

Comment: yes, date picker appears but then timeout, so I am wondering a step to click on the date first to switch, I tried `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//th[@class='switch'])[2]"))).click()` but still timeout

Comment: Hey, I tried your new code, but still not worked, I think the `"div.ms-parent.single_select2 button div"` is the select button on the left of the datepicker? not sure, but still time out... it won't click on the datepicker to switch month

Comment: @Cathy please try the updated code above. It seem like the web page slow response, so even you've performed `datefield_st.click()`, it doesn't make the date picker always appear. Before clicking on it it seems like you have to wait for other elements to load completely. Also the wait increase to be 30s `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)`

Comment: yes, I tried the new code but the month's xpath seems still invalid as it returns error

Comment: still `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException`, I think it cannot locate the element